# How to Get latest folder details dynamically in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have folders in this path `C:\Customer\`

Folder Names:

```
04012019
04022019
04032019
...
```

I want to pick the latest folder(`04032019`) dynamically.

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this in ssis .

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this without using script task.
First of all you need to create a table in `SQL Server`

```
CREATE TABLE folder_Name (id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
      , folder VARCHAR(512)
      , depth INT)
```

and then run the below `SQL` statement to insert the folder name into the table **folder_Name**.

```
INSERT INTO @tbl (folder, depth)
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree 'C:\Client',1,0;
```

After this we can compare the value and assign this to a variable for selecting that folder and then you can read all files data using loop or sequence container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Script Task to achieve that:

1. In the package, create a variable of type string (example: `@[User::FolderPath]`)
2. Add a Script Task
3. Select `@[User:FolderPath` as `ReadWriteVariable`
4. Use a similar Script :

*First you have to add `using System.Linq;` to use Linq functionalities within the script*

```cs
public void Main()
{

    //Change the root folder value an specify the main directory that contains the folders you need to process
    string rootfolder = @"C:\Customer\";
    DateTime dt;
    string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootfolder, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    string maxdatefoldername = folders.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x))
        .Where(y => DateTime.TryParseExact(y,"MMddyyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out dt) == true)
        .OrderByDescending(z => DateTime.ParseExact(z, "MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)).FirstOrDefault();

    string maxfolder = folders.Where(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x) == maxdatefoldername).FirstOrDefault();

    Dts.Variables["User:FolderPath"].Value = maxfolder;

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error in script task.error is "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." .Could you please help me.

Comment: @Balu this is not the real exception. Check the following link https://data-dev.blogspot.com/2019/04/ssis-script-task-error-exception-has.html?m=1

Comment: @Balu i tested the code and it is working perfectly. Check that you the variable name is correct (case sensitive) and that all date values are valid